# Cannot send updated object values from a client to a server, server reads values that do not exist

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, observer-pattern

I'm making an online game for a school assignment.  Two users connect to a server and play a co-op turn based game where they try to beat an enemy.  When I send the GameCharacter object from the client to the server AFTER the first time, it does not retain the updated values, only the initial values that was sent the first time.  The assignment MUST include threading and the observer pattern as well.

Below are the snippets from the classes that give the issue.  This is from an instance of 1 client to 1 server.

```
//Sending from the client to the server
synchronized public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) 
{

    if (evt.getNewValue() instanceof GameCharacter)
    {
        //First time the code is run, all values are initialized.  Current hp is 350.
        //Second time the code is run, several values are updated. Current hp is 100
        GameCharacter test = (GameCharacter) evt.getNewValue();
        try 
        {

            this.player = test;

            System.out.println(test.getCurrentHp() + " Is the characters current hp in Client");
            dos.writeObject(test);
        } catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Error sending character to server" ); 
        }
    }
}
```

```
//The server immediately after receiving the object

//This is defined in the constructor
private ObjectInputStream ois;

@Override
public void run() 
{
    Object superTempHolder = null;
    while (true)
    {
        try 
        {
            superTempHolder = ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("I don't know how to receive.");
            fixIOException(ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("I don't know what that is.");
            fixClassNotFoundException(ex);
        }
        //If statement added for testing purposes
        if (superTempHolder instanceof GameCharacter)
        {
            GameCharacter tester = (GameCharacter) superTempHolder;
            System.out.println(tester.getCurrentHp() + " Is the current hp of the character in InputListener");
        }
        listener.propertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, Integer.toString(this.id), null, superTempHolder));
    }
}
```

Output from the client

```
350 Is the characters current hp in Client
100 Is the characters current hp in Client
```

Output from the server

```
350 Is the current hp of the character in InputListener
350 Is the current hp of the character in InputListener
```

This is the only way that this program can send a GameCharacter from the client to the server.  GameCharacter is completely serialized, and I'm not sure where it's pulling the 350 from when it sends the second time since there's effectively only one instance of GameCharacter that exists on the client.

Ultimately, the issue is: It correctly sends the object, but not the updated values, and the server somehow reads information that doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [`reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()) method in ObjectOutputStream.

> Reset will disregard the state of any objects already written to the stream. The state is reset to be the same as a new `ObjectOutputStream`. The current point in the stream is marked as reset so the corresponding `ObjectInputStream` will be reset at the same point. Objects previously written to the stream will not be refered to as already being in the stream. They will be written to the stream again.

You should call reset before writing the same object again.

You can also use [`writeUnshared`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared(java.lang.Object)) method. If you decide to use writeUnshared, you should look into [`readUnshared`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readUnshared()) method from `ObjectInputStream`.